# Differences between command line and scheduled execution with `at` causing unresponsive Chrome

Tags: chrome, at

I have a python script which controls Google Chrome via selenium and chromedriver. It runs perfectly from the command line.

When I schedule it using `at`, Chrome is successfully started, it opens up on my screen, but it fails to load the webpage (no error message shown) and then Chrome becomes unresponsive.

I checked my $PATH, and other environment variables, it seems like everything is preserved when the `at` command runs.

I also tried appending

```
export DISPLAY=":0";
```

to the beginning of my `at` command like this:

```
echo 'export DISPLAY=":0"; python ~/Documents/script.py' | at -t 201712122245
```

still had the same issue...

When I edit the script so it runs Chrome in headless mode, it works. But the website doesn't load certain elements when the browser is in headless mode so I need it to work without using headless mode.

Can you think of any differences between a command run at the command line, and a command started by `at` that could be responsible for this behavior?

Comment: I tried something else, which also failed. I created a bash script, that called my python script, and then I scheduled the bash script with `at`.